# TickerをCTRL+Cで止める正しいやり方が知りたい

Tags: go

やりたいこと

- 無限ループの中で<kbd>Enter</kbd>押下で1を出力する。
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>押下でプログラムを終了する

できないこと

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>を押下してもプログラムが終了しない

```go
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    sig := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(sig, syscall.SIGINT)
    r := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    t := time.NewTicker(time.Duration(1) * time.Millisecond)
loop:
    for {
        select {
        case <-sig:
            fmt.Println("sigint")
            break loop
        case <-t.C:
            r.ReadRune()
            fmt.Println(1)
        }
    }

    t.Stop()
}
```

こんな感じで書いてみたんですが、<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>でプログラム終了が出来ません。
Tickerの使い方もこれでいいのか・・・アドバイスお願いします。

Comment: 入力があれば1を出力するだけのプログラムを組めば、SIGINTが来たときは勝手に終了しますが、そうではなく、自前でシグナルを扱いたいということでしょうか？

Comment: `sig := make(chan os.Signal)` となっていますが、`For a channel used for notification of just one signal value, a buffer of size 1 is sufficient.` ですので、`sig := make(chan os.Signal, 1)` とする必要があります。また、`r.ReadRune()` で入力待ちになってしまいますので、入力が行われるまでシグナルの処理がペンディング状態になります。

Comment: nekketsuuuさん 今後拡張していきたいため自前でシグナルを扱いたいです。

Comment: metropolisさん makeの件勉強になりました。ペンディング状態、となるとループの中で```r.ReadRune()```を使うと自前で用意したSIGINTのチェックが効かないのは仕様ということでしょうか？

Comment: この場合、同じ select 文の中に `<- sig` と `r.ReadRune()` がありますので、例えば入力待ちの状態で Control-c と Return キー(newline)を打てば `sigint` と表示されてプログラムが終了するかもしれません。「かもしれない」というのは、1ms の間隔で ticker の割り込みが入るので、タイミングによっては何回かキー入力を行なわないと SIGINT に対する処理が行われないからです。Control-c の入力と同時にSIGINT の処理を行いたい場合は、例えば goroutine で SIGINT の割り込みを待つ方法があるかと思います。https://play.golang.org/p/fnwM4jEX84 playgorund ではキー入力ができませんので、ローカル環境にコピーして実行してみて下さい。

Comment: このやり方でうまくいきそうです。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @metropolis この内容は回答として投稿なさいますか？